# UINavigation controller Push and Pop

Tags: iphone, controller, uinavigationcontroller

I have to pop to HomeScreenViewController from current view controller after clicking on custom back button, which is added on main window as a light box. I used following code :

```
HomeScreenViewController *homeController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:homeController animated:YES];
    [homeController release];
```

I got crashing with exception : `Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.`

How can it be implemented? What changes are required for implementing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clearly you are creating a new instance of `HomeScreenViewController` which doesn't exist on the navigation stack. You will have to get the existing instance and use it as an argument for `popToViewController:animated:` method. You can do it by getting the view controller from the `viewControllers` array which is a property on `UINavigationController`. They are indexed in order so if the view controller is at index 1 then get the view controller using

```
UIViewController * viewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

If you want to go back to root view controller, use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` instead.

Comment: Thaks. Thanks a lot. Really it helped me a lot. On that basis I did some thing new, which was required for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this friend

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES/NO];
```

Comment: Actually this code jumps me at very first index, which was not my question. I had to jump on intermediate level. About code posted by Deepak helped me in the same way. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget about this code in your AppDelegate (.m):

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

self.navigationController = navigationController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and in AppDelegate (.h)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

It can be problem sometimes, when you customizing a lot things in your app.